# How can i check if FormCollection["key"] exists

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, listbox, formcollection

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 3 and I post a form in my view, containing a `@Html.ListBoxFor`

When I receive the posted form as a FormCollection, how can I check if an item was selected in the ListBox?

In my controller there seems to be no item named `collection["Company.RepresentingCountries"]` since no `<select>` option was selected.. This results in a "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error message when I try to check for it! What's the protocol here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't shown how your `ListBoxFor` helper is defined, so I can only be guessing here. This being said you talked about `FormCollection` which usage I wouldn't recommend. What I recommend is using view models. So let's take an example:

Model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select at least one item")]
    public string[] SelectedItemIds { get; set; }

    public SelectListItem[] Items
    {
        get
        {
            return new[]
            {
                new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "Item 1" },
                new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "Item 2" },
                new SelectListItem { Value = "3", Text = "Item 3" },
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new MyViewModel
        {
            SelectedItemIds = new[] { "1", "3" }
        };
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        { 
            // The model is valid we know that the user selected
            // at least one item => model.SelectedItemIds won't be null
            // Do some processing ...
        }
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model MyViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ListBoxFor(
        x => x.SelectedItemIds, 
        new SelectList(Model.Items, "Value", "Text")
    )
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.SelectedItemIds)
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
}
```

Comment: Thank's I'll try to do it like that.. So the main thing is the "ModelState.IsValid pretty much..?

Comment: @Niclas Lindqvist, `ModelState.IsValid` will ensure that all validation rules you have put on your view model are respected.

Comment: doesn't answer the question in the title

Comment: @DaveO, when answering a question on SO, personally I prefer to take into account the OP's scenario in order to provide the best possible answer according to me instead of just blindly and literally answering the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can access form contents in this way:

```
foreach (var key in Request.Form.AllKeys)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}:{1}", key, Request.Form[key]));
}
```

You can see what you wrote to Debug with tool like DebugView.
Of course, you can set a breakpoint here or inspect this collection in any other manner.

<select> always has 'selected' value when posting (if user has not chosen it, then it is the first option that was in it), so if you set "empty" default, it will be posted in collection and its value will be "" (string.Empty).

**UPDATE** When select has multiple="multiple" attribute, then none selected value means that form serialization will not take it into account, so it wont be part of form collection. To check if you have selected value, use `collection["Company.RepresentingCountries"] == null`, or `String.IsNullOrEmpty(collection["Company.RepresentingCountries"])`. Both will be true when there is no selected value, although second one might be true in case you have empty option in select.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer, probably should have mentioned that the ListBoxFor creates a `<select multiple="multiple">`, thus it doesn't seem like it has a 'selected' by default, so there's no key named Company.RepresentingCountries in my FormCollection.

Comment: I have checked multiple case with no selected value. It does not get serialized into form collection. I will update my answer now.

Comment: Thanks for the update, I actually still got the error when doing                 `if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(collection["Company.RepresentingCountries"]))`
But perhaps checking for null would have done the trick!

Comment: Well, I tried both (made multiselect on form that I work on and posted back to controller), and it worked, and you could get exception only when indexing collection, so you will get it and when checking for null. I will check alternatives for this now.

Comment: Which version of mvc are you using? I don't get the error, even collection.GetValue("adfasdf") returns null, not exception for me.